# How i can stop a function and run again?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

i have a problem with my discord bot.

i have a function with questions, and i have a restart function but i don't know how to stop function and run again.

```
async function restart(channel) {
            builderquestions(channel)
        }
        async function builderquestions(channel) {
            const intrebarea = await channel.send({ embed: { color, title: title[0], description: description[0], footer: { text: rescloseed } } })
            await intrebarea.react('♻️')
            await intrebarea.react('❌')
            const collector = intrebarea.createReactionCollector((reaction, user) => message.guild.members.cache.find((member) => member.id === user.id), { dispose: true });
            collector.on("collect", async (reaction, user) => {
                switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
                    case "♻️": {
                        reaction.users.remove(user.id);
                        await restart(channel);
                        break;
                    }
                    case "❌": {
                        reaction.users.remove(user.id);
                        closeticket(channel)
                        break;
                    }
                }
            })
            const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
            channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time, errors: ["time"] })
                .then(async (collected) => {
                    const msg = collected.first();
                    map.set("answer2", msg.content)

                    if (msg) {
                        msg.delete();
                        intrebarea.edit({ embed: { color, title: title[1], description: description[1], footer: { text: rescloseed } } })
                        const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
                        channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time, errors: ["time"] })
                            .then(async (collected) => {
                                const msg = collected.first();
                                map.set("answer3", msg.content)

                                if (msg) {
                                    msg.delete();
                                    intrebarea.edit({ embed: { color, title: title[2], description: description[2], footer: { text: rescloseed } } })
                                    const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
                                    channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time, errors: ["time"] })
                                        .then(async (collected) => {
                                            const msg = collected.first();
                                            map.set("answer4", msg.content)

                                            if (msg) {
                                                msg.delete();
                                                intrebarea.edit({ embed: { color, title: title[3], description: description[3], footer: { text: rescloseed } } })
                                                const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
                                                channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time, errors: ["time"] })
                                                    .then(async (collected) => {
                                                        const msg = collected.first();
                                                        map.set("answer5", msg.content)

                                                        if (msg) {
                                                            msg.delete();
                                                            intrebarea.edit({ embed: { color, title: title[4], description: description[4], footer: { text: rescloseed } } })
                                                            const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
                                                            channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time, errors: ["time"] })
                                                                .then(async (collected) => {
                                                                    const msg = collected.first();
                                                                    map.set("answer6", msg.content)

                                                                    if (msg) {
                                                                        msg.delete();
                                                                        intrebarea.edit({ embed: { color, title: title[5], description: description[5], footer: { text: rescloseed } } })
                                                                        const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
                                                                        channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time, errors: ["time"] })
                                                                            .then(async (collected) => {
                                                                                const msg = collected.first();
                                                                                map.set("answer7", msg.content)

                                                                                if (msg) {
                                                                                    msg.delete();
                                                                                    intrebarea.edit({ embed: { color, title: title[6], description: description[6], footer: { text: rescloseed } } })
                                                                                    const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
                                                                                    channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time, errors: ["time"] })
                                                                                        .then(async (collected) => {
                                                                                            const msg = collected.first();
                                                                                            map.set("answer8", msg.content)

                                                                                            if (msg) {
                                                                                                msg.delete();
                                                                                                intrebarea.edit({ embed: { color, title: title[7], description: description[7], footer: { text: rescloseed } } })
                                                                                                const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
                                                                                                channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time, errors: ["time"] })
                                                                                                    .then(async (collected) => {
                                                                                                        const msg = collected.first();
                                                                                                        map.set("answer9", msg.content)

                                                                                                        if (msg) {
                                                                                                            msg.delete();
                                                                                                            intrebarea.edit({ embed: { color, title: "Commission Info", description: `**Ticket: <#${channel.id}>**\n**Role**: Builder\n\n**${title[0]}**\n${map.get("answer2")}\n**${title[1]}?**\n${map.get("answer3")}\n**${title[2]}**\n${map.get("answer4")}\n**${title[3]}**\n${map.get("answer5")}\n**${title[4]}**\n${map.get("answer6")}\n**${title[5]}**\n${map.get("answer7")}\n**${title[6]}**\n${map.get("answer8")}\n**${title[7]}**\n${map.get("answer9")}`, footer: { text: copyright } } })
                                                                                                            const question = await channel.send({
                                                                                                                embed: { color: "266DFF", title: "Please react with:", description: "✔️ to complete,♻️ to restart, or ❌ to exit", footer: { text: copyright } }
                                                                                                            })
                                                                                                            await question.react('✔️');
                                                                                                            await question.react('♻️')
                                                                                                            await question.react('❌');
                                                                                                            const collector = question.createReactionCollector((reaction, user) => message.guild.members.cache.find((member) => member.id === user.id), { dispose: true });
                                                                                                            collector.on("collect", async (reaction, user) => {
                                                                                                                switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
                                                                                                                    case "❌": {
                                                                                                                        reaction.users.remove(user.id);
                                                                                                                        closeticket(channel)
                                                                                                                        break;
                                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                                    case "♻️": {
                                                                                                                        reaction.users.remove(user.id);
                                                                                                                        restart(channel)
                                                                                                                        break;
                                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                                    case "✔️": {

                                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                                }
                                                                                                            })
                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                    })
                                                                                            }
                                                                                        })
                                                                                }
                                                                            })

                                                                    }
                                                                })
                                                        }
                                                    })
                                            }
                                        })
                                }
                            })
                    }
                    if (!msg) return message.reply("Operation canceled");
                })

        }
```

When I start restart function, my builderquestion function continue to work.I tried many things, but they didn't work.

**If you have an idea, you can leave it.**

Comment: My dude... you have so much code repetition. You can definitely turn that repeated chain into a module or a function at least using async/await.

Comment: Please come up with a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also please format the code better.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't read the code at all, but to stop and restart the function insert this where You need:

```js
return builderquestions();
```

The keyword `return` makes the function stop, and `builderquestions()` makes the function run again.

This should work.